# An error "NSInternalInconsistencyException" is thrown by AgentSDK within Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I've created a new middle ware assembly(some code snippets list below) using object-c binding project within Xamarin in order to invoke AgentSDK.h of MobiControl SDK. The assembly is compiled and referenced successfully while it is an error "NSInternalInconsistencyException" as below thrown in AgentSDK.h initialization. Can anyone help me to resolve this error? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code snippets:

```
// @interface AgentSdkCore : NSObject

    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject),Name="AgentSdkCore")]
    interface AgentSdkCore
    {
        // @property (atomic, strong) NSString * agentURI;
        [Export("agentURI", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
        string AgentURI { get; set; }

        // @property (readonly, atomic) BOOL appConfigAvailable;
        [Export("appConfigAvailable")]
        bool AppConfigAvailable { get; }

        // +(AgentSdkCore *)getInstance;
        [Static]
        [Export("getInstance")]
        AgentSdkCore Instance { get; }
```

And here are exception:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Can't be zero. Binary built incorrectly!
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010804fb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108450141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108053cf2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001046c9536 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   testsss                             0x0000000103f3fe9b -[DataStorage managedObjectModel] + 301
    5   testsss                             0x0000000103f402ad -[DataStorage persistentStoreCoordinator] + 89
    6   testsss                             0x0000000103f3fcd7 -[DataStorage managedObjectContext] + 59
    7   testsss                             0x0000000103f3f8c8 __21-[DataStorage initDB]_block_invoke + 37
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c994792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c9793de _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 126
    10  testsss                             0x0000000103f3f855 -[DataStorage initDB] + 299
    11  testsss                             0x0000000103f3f6f2 -[DataStorage init] + 163
    12  testsss                             0x0000000103f4042d __33+[DataStorage defaultDataStorage]_block_invoke + 38
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c994792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c97fa8d dispatch_once_f + 69
    15  testsss                             0x0000000103f40405 +[DataStorage defaultDataStorage] + 102
    16  testsss                             0x0000000103eeee53 -[MobiControlMessageManager init] + 80
    17  testsss                             0x0000000103eeefd8 __61+[MobiControlMessageManager defaultMobiControlMessageManager]_block_invoke + 38
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c994792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c97fa8d dispatch_once_f + 69
    20  testsss                             0x0000000103eeefb0 +[MobiControlMessageManager defaultMobiControlMessageManager] + 102
    21  testsss                             0x0000000103f23eaa -[AgentSdkCore init] + 499
    22  testsss                             0x000000010423ec39 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
    23  ???                                 0x0000000115fdfc6b 0x0 + 4663934059
    24  testsss                             0x00000001040ab9a5 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1301
    25  testsss                             0x000000010415fcb8 do_runtime_invoke + 88
    26  testsss                             0x000000010415fc30 mono_runtime_invoke + 208
    27  testsss                             0x00000001042374d5 xamarin_invoke_trampoline + 5589
    28  testsss                             0x000000010423d6ed xamarin_arch_trampoline + 189
    29  testsss                             0x000000010423eab1 xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline + 110
    30  UIKit                               0x00000001053a6d82 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010552b5ac -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010552b8c7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010552a802 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    34  UIKit                               0x00000001054147ea -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    35  UIKit                               0x0000000105415f00 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    36  UIKit                               0x00000001053c2a84 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000105ba65d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    38  UIKit                               0x0000000105b9e532 __handleEventQueue + 1122
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107ff5c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107fdb0cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107fda5ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107fda016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109603a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    44  UIKit                               0x00000001053a5134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    45  ???                                 0x00000001159d2324 0x0 + 4657586980
    46  ???                                 0x00000001159d1f5d 0x0 + 4657586013
```